# How to reset multiple counters with one button in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The TLDR of my question is that each of my child components keeps and displays its own counter clicks. Each of those clicks also updates a `Total` that is displayed. I'd like to know how to have the `Reset` button to also have those children components reset.

I have an app that displays a total, a number of buttons that each increment the total in a different way and a reset button. *In this small app weights is an array full of different weight objects*

```
class CountersContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      total: 0,
    }
    this.resetTotal = this.resetTotal.bind(this)
    this.updateTotalByWeights = this.updateTotalByWeights.bind(this)
  }

  resetTotal = () => {
    this.setState({
      total: 0,
    })
  }

  updateTotalByWeights = value => {
    this.setState({ 
        total: this.state.total + value * 2,
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container">
          {weights.map(w => (
            <Weight
              key={w.kg}
              incrementTotal={this.updateTotalByWeights}
              weight={w.kg}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <button className="click-target" onClick={this.resetTotal}>
          reset
        </button>
        <WeightOutput total={this.state.total} units={this.state.metric} />
      </>
    )
  }

/=============
// The weight component
/=============
import React from "react"

const Weight = ({ incrementTotal, weight }) => {

    return (
        <div onClick={() => { incrementTotal(weight) }} >
          {weight}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Weight
```

This works fine. I'd like each `Weight` component to keep count of the number of times its been clicked. So if the `5kg` weight component is clicked twice it will show a count of 2, along with updating the total in the desired fashion. So I added the following to my weight component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react"

const Weight = ({ incrementTotal, weight }) => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    return (
        <div
            onClick={
                () => { 
                        incrementTotal(weight) 
                        setCount(count + 1)
                    }
                }
         >  
                {count > 0 && <span>{count}</span>}
                {weight}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Weight
```

This achieves the desired result of total being incremented correctly and the components count being updated each click.

However, now I need to change my reset button to reset each weight components `count` and I'm completely at a loss for how to approach this. Some things I've considered are forcing each Weight to Re-render, keeping the "counts" further up the hierarchy. Perhaps a "hook" is the wrong implementation here (this little app is an attempt to get comfortable with hook primarily). Ideal answers will include both how to approach the problem along with potential solutions.

*notes: I'm not sure that the above code is perfect, I've tried to strip out the parts that were not relevant to the question. Below I've added what the weight data looks like in case anyone is curious.*

```
export const weights = [
         {
           color: "red",
           kg: 25,
           lbs: 55,
         },
         {
           color: "blue",
           kg: 20,
           lbs: 45,
         },
// this goes on a while.
```

**UPDATE**

I've updated my weight component to look like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

const Weight = props => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
      setCount(0)
    }, [props.reset])

    return (
      <div
        onClick={() => {
          props.incrementTotal(props.weight)
          setCount(count + 1)
        }}
      >
        {count > 0 && <span>{count}</span>}
        {props.weight}
      </div>
    )
}

export default Weight
```

And added `reset: 0` to my reset setState function. This hasn't solved my problem but does seem a promising  direction per the React Hook Docs.

*Update 2*
I accepted the answer below because it was correct though I failed to understand it fully. In order to implement the below solution I had to update the "reset" value. I did this by passing.

I'm not sure this is a *good* solution. I believe it's re-rendering all weight components. Which potentially is bad, especially if there's a 1000 components that are complicated.

```
this.setState({
   reset: !this.state.reset
})
```

Comment: As you are managing `count` in the component `state` so you need to pass a props to the component `reset` and on change that props you need to change your state to `0`

Comment: These components seem a lot like a form. If they were a form, you'd have access to a `reset` button, which reinitializes form state. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: thanks @JakeWorth. unfortunately, in this case, this is not a form in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a prop with different value from parent to `Weight` child components whenever you want to reset counters and use `useEffect` hook with dependency as that prop. e.g

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = { reset: Date.now() };
  
  resetCounters = () => {
      this.setState({ reset: Date.now() });
  }
  render () {
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.resetCounters} >Reset</button>
      <Wieght reset={this.state.reset} {..some other props} />
      <Wieght reset={this.state.reset} {..some other props} />
      <Wieght reset={this.state.reset} {..some other props} />
      <Wieght reset={this.state.reset} {..some other props} />
    </div>
  }
}


const Weight = props => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    setCounter(0);
  }, [props.reset]);

}
```

Another option is to pass `reset` as key to Weight component so, on changing the key, it will remount. This is a simple solution but can cause performance issues for large number of Weight components

Comment: I tried something similar to passing a `key` and toggling that from true to false. I was unable to implement it correctly and was concerned that it was a solution that was less than ideal.  I'll try to implement your solution.

Comment: I read the docs because of what you linked and since count is used inside the hook component here
        {count > 0 && <span>{count}</span>} 
is that causing this issue? Since it's not held elsewhere?  (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)